# Fan-made(?) comics about the next Avatar

Tags: story-identification, the-legend-of-korra

A friend sent me a link to an online comics about 3 years ago.
I am not sure if it was Fan-made or not, because the quality of the drawing was really good.

I did not have time to read it at the time and wanted to save it for later, but I forgot about it and now it's lost (He can't find it either).

I read the first chapter, what I can remember is Korra 'visiting' the next Earthbender Avatar, bringing warnings about dangers that are coming to the world, and apologising that she is the only help available, while she had many Avatars she could talk to.

Comment: I wrote an answer linking to *The Legend of Niiko*, but then found proof that Korra was dead at the start of the comic, plus Niiko is a waterbender.

Comment: Korra has to die for a new avatar to be born. I will check it out anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Ofcourse I meant 'spiritually' visited

Answer (score 5):

I will try with ["The Legend of Genji"](https://legendofgenji.com)

An avatar fancomic, where the avatar seems to be Genji, a sandbender. I haven't found yet a chapter to read, but be sure I'm on it. However I looks like the project started only a year ago (oldest news is from 2018).
[image: The Legend of Gengi]

Comment: that's not the one, but thank you so much for letting me know about it!